# Does a current carrying circular wire expand due to its own magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, magnetic-fields, electric-current, magnetic-moment

Here is a thought experiment:
Since two parallel current carrying wires repel each other, does the same hold true for any element of a **circular current carrying wire** and thus the wire **expands** radially outwards?

The problem with this experiment is, that only infinite parallel wires repel each other and that the whole result is counterintuitive for me.

I assume the wire does not heat up and high amperes are possible.

Comment: *two parallel current carrying wires repel each other*. No, parallel currents **attract** each other.

Comment: Actually, for parallel wires there are two cases: if the currents are also *parallel* (same direction) then the wires *attract, if the currents are anti-parallel (opposite direction) then the wires repel.

Comment: It compresses. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinch_(plasma_physics)

Comment: I saw this when I was in high school in the 1970's. I was surprised to see it on the internet. But perhaps I shouldn't be. It is hokey, but it makes the answer very clear. [Magnetic Force between Parallel Wires](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kapi6ZDvoRs)

Comment: Do you mean a **closed** current **loop**?  The Lorentz force will be **radially outward** making the loop as taut as possible and hence will be circular in shape finally.  See the case for elliptic loop in a journal article [*here*](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0004-637X/771/2/125).

Answer (score 18):

Since current elements moving in parallel attract (not repel!) each other, the electrons inside a wire do in fact feel an attractive magnetic force towards the center of the wire.  However, if they moved inwards, their density would increase, causing there to be a net negative charge density inside the wire and pushing them back out.  Equilibrium is reached when the electric force on the electrons from the *net* charge density (positive ions + electrons) balances the attractive magnetic force between the electrons.

This means that the interior of the wire carries a net negative volume charge.  There will be a corresponding positive charge on the surface of the wire to ensure that the wire as a whole is electrically neutral.

If the current is sufficiently large, this can actually deform the metal (due to the forces between the electrons and the positive ions.)  This can more readily be observed in hollow metal conductors, where the walls can collapse inwards if enough force is applied.  The tube below, for example, was a section of a lightning rod that was ["pinched"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinch_%28plasma_physics%29) by the current in the lightning strike.

[image]